# How to plot individual case residuals (ICRs) from lavaan model?

Tags: regression, residuals, structural-equation-modeling, assumptions

I was reading [this article](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0013164413487905) on saturated models in structural equation modeling (SEM) and it appears they describe a tool for checking how well the model fits data even if the model fit indices indicate a "perfect fit" under raw data misspecification. They simply take the individual case residuals (ICRs) and plot them against a variable of interest or parameter not included in the original SEM. They can be seen below, which are just the scatterplots of these checks:

[image]

However, I was curious how one can obtain this information in packages like `lavaan` or otherwise, as the examples they give are in Stata. I am aware one can get residuals by running `resid(fit)` or something similar with `lavResiduals`, but these typically only give you residual matrices. Is there a way of obtaining ICRs in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way of obtaining ICRs in R?

Not directly, but there is a relatively new method for obtaining casewise predicted values in SEM:

de Rooij, M., Karch, J. D., Fokkema, M., Bakk, Z., Pratiwi, B. C., & Kelderman, H. (2023). SEM-based out-of-sample predictions. *Structural Equation Modeling, 30*(1), 132-148. https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2022.2061494

This is implemented in the new `lavPredictY()` function.  Once you save predicted values, you can easily subtract those from observed values to get casewise residuals.  Jarrett Byrnes recently shared some code for his own `lavResidualsY()` function that could help:

https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues/269

Comment: Wow thanks for that. I'll give it a whirl.